# Is it possible to convert e.target.property to a value and use it to reference an object?

Tags: javascript

The simplified code below does not work but I hope it helps to illuminate the idea I'm testing.

`e.target.id` returns the name of the id that initiated the function call.  In this case it's the id `target`.  Since `target` is also an object I thought maybe I could reference a key inside the `target` object.  In this case `.name`. As structured this does not work at all.  Do I need to process `e.target.id` before I use it as a reference?  Is this possible at all?

1) I'm aware this might possibly be categorized under worst practices.

2) I'm testing how far I can push JS.

```js
'use strict';

var target = {
  name: 'it worked'
}

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  alert(e.target.id.name);  //dies right here
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't address your issue, but you forgot the `function` keyword.

Comment: you can get the `name` property like this: `e.target.name`

Comment: I don't think so.  Doesn't it have to be `e.target.id` to return the word `target`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with `eval` or as @Slai mentioned with `window[e.target.id]`.

Be careful with eval:
[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

```js
var target = {
  name: 'it worked'
}

document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction(e) {
  //alert(eval(e.target.id).name);  
  alert(window[e.target.id].name);
}
```

```html
<div id="target">div</div>
```

Comment: @DR01D no need for eval .. `alert(window[e.target.id].name)`. Just noticed it's the answer in the duplicate question

Comment: @Slai That's right!